# How to block switching screen mode

Tags: stride

When the game is full screen, pressing the window key switches the game screen to windowed mode.
How can I block this?
I tried to find related to this in official documentation
But I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I've never had this issue. But this would work in the same way as on other apps. You might want to catch the key code and set it to handled, depending on whether you use Winforms or SDL context, it might work differently.